# sending structured formfields trhough jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have omitted all irrelevant tags:

```
<form id="loginform">
    <input name=login[username] />
</form>
<script
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'login.php',
        data: {
            action : 'login',
            formData : $('#loginform').serialize()
        },
        type: 'post',
        async: 'true',
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
    });
</script>
```

I have tried with

when in PHP I do a print_r($_POST) I would like to receive the following data:

```
Array {
    action = login
    formData = Array {
        login = Array {
            username = xxxxxxx
        }
    }
}
```

I need it to implement it in my (first) jquery mobile project as I'm used to using that in all my other projects. It saves me so much time on PHP development if the posted data is already structured.

I have tried:

```
formData : $('#loginform').serialize()
```

and

```
formData : $('#loginform').serializeArray()
```

I can of course use:

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append(...);
```

but I like a more general, always usable without (much) edit, solution, similar to the serialize version.

Comment: I'm not sure, but using `login['username']` instead of `login[username]` might help

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP coder, but it looks like your PHP code wants an `Array`, but is being sent a string value instead.  You will have to do `Split(';')` and `Split('=')` function in PHP to parse the serialized data to an array.  Or don't expect an array in your PHP and request each field individually, then you can do this instead:

```
   ...
   data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
```

Then add this in your form:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"/>
```